# ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, exception, windows-phone-8.1

In my `XAML` page I have added some resource

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Button x:Key="btn" Content="Test Button"></Button>
    ...
</Page.Resources>
```

In my code file I am calling this resource but getting runtime exception. Cant understand what happens. Please advice

```
Button btn = this.Resources["btn"] as Button;
if (btn != null)
{
    MyPivotItem.Content = btn; // here I am getting the exception 
                               // "Value does not fall within the expected range"
}
```

Comment: `MyPivotItem.Content` <-- is this a button?

Comment: `MyPivotItem` is a `PivotItem`, I am adding `btn` as `Content`

Comment: Could you be missing a namespace declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a FrameworkElement (a Control) in Resources. A control can only be a child of one other element, that is you cannot reuse it, just put it in one place and that's it. And if you put it as resource, it seems that it becomes child of the control in which you put it.

If you want to reuse some control, make a [UserControl](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/why-and-how-to-create-a-user-control-in-windows-phone) or [Custom/Template Control](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/creating-a-wp7-custom-control-in-7-steps) and use it instead. Here's a comparison between the two types of controls: [link](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/user-control-vs-custom-control-in-silverlight-for-wp7)

The links may not be the perfect tutorials, but I think they'll be a fine start.

Comment: (+1) Right. Also a `Template` instead `UserControl` could be here a solution.

Comment: Yep, I was just editing my answer to include that option and also add some useful links. :)